# mock a web service only for test purpose

Tags: java, web-services, mocking

i am working on integration tests, getting Responses from An API A.
the API A interacts with another API B which also calls a web Service to get data from it.

the problem is the data may change in the future, so the integration tests may fail and as long as the data changes, i have to edit the tests too to make it work.

i want to Mock the web service from which i have the data, but i don't know how to tell API B to call the mock only for tests,
does anyone has an idea about the best way to do this ?

Comment: If APIs A and B run in the same JVM instance as the integration test, then you should be able to mock the web service client (represented by a Java class) so that it returns some fixed test data.

Comment: the web service from which i have data is a soap web service, so in my API B, i call a client, but only to test , i want to mock the returned data from the client, and in normal cases API B interacts with the other client, how do i have to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like http://rest-assured.io/ or http://wiremock.org/.
With this you can your API calls will be done the same like you would normally (probably you need to change the hostname). Then you can give a certain result on a URI, Content-Type, etc.

It is even possible to do assertion, to see if the request actual took place, and can do some checking on the requested content.

Comment: thank you for your answer, in my API B i have a reference to the ip address (in application context Spring ) to the Web Service that is called, so if i use  wireMock for example, how can i change it only for tests ?

Comment: @manu Make the IP address configurable. If you use spring already you can take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: so you are saying, that when i am testing i can change the properties file ? to edit the ip address used ?

Comment: @manu Exactly, in your test you will override the normal configuration, which then points to another endpoint.

Comment: how do i do that ? knowing that for my integration test i am using another application that calls API A -> API B,,, it doesn't call directly API B